# ORA-00936: missing expression(UPDATED)

Tags: oracle11g

```
UPDATE TBL_TRAIN_LIST SET SEAT=t.TOTAL 
(SELECT ANAM.NAME,ANAM.SEAT,ANAM2.TRAIN_NAME,
 ANAM2.SEAT,  ANAM2.SEAT - ANAM.SEAT  AS TOTAL 
 FROM TBL_PASSENGER ANAM, TBL_TRAIN_LIST ANAM2 
WHERE ANAM.NO=ANAM2.ID ) t
where TBL_TRAIN_LIST.ID=TBL_PASSENGER.NO;
```

Comment: And your question is? If I had to guess, I'd say you are looking for the `SET` clause in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: YES         POLITANK YOU ARE RIGHT

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax doesn't looks correct. Try changing your query to something like below

```
UPDATE  
(SELECT ANAM.NAME,
ANAM.SEAT as NEWSEAT,
ANAM2.TRAIN_NAME,
ANAM2.SEAT,  
ANAM2.SEAT - ANAM.SEAT  AS TOTAL 
FROM TBL_PASSENGER ANAM
INNER JOIN TBL_TRAIN_LIST ANAM2 
ON ANAM.NO = ANAM2.ID ) t
SET t.NEWSEAT = t.TOTAL;
```

Comment: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Comment: Rahul  bro  now error is "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"

Comment: That's not the issue with the query in answer rather looks like a issue with your column definition. I mean size of the column. Looks like that's a float/double type column,